# Alternative for using set methods when creating a new object

Tags: java, oop

So I am trying to create a program that helps me keep track of my expenses and i have a question to do with how I create my objects.

So far i have been creating my objects like so:

```
Grocery milk = new Grocery();

    milk.setName("Milk");
    milk.setCost(2.84);
    milk.setDate(30, 12, 2014);
    milk.setType("Food");
```

My grocery class extends this expense class:

```
public Expense(){}
public Expense(String name, Double cost, Calendar purchaseDate){
    name =  _name;
    cost = _cost;
    purchaseDate = _purchaseDate;

}
```

So far my grocery class only adds another string parameter that i call type, and so here is my question:

Instead of using set methods to set my paramters for each new created object i would like to do it like this:

```
Grocery milk = new Grocery("Milk", 2.84, ??Date??, "Food")
```

But the date parameter is a little more complicated than the other parameters that are just of type string and double, is there a way to do what I want or am i better off using the set methods?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why don't you try to store `date` as a string or a [`Date` object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)?

Comment: This is tangentially related to your question, but for value classes like this I would strongly recommend making them **immutable** as well - mark all their fields as `final`, and set them in the constructor.  This makes many things easier to reason about - and would also catch what looks like a bug in your `Expense` constructor, where you *don't set the fields at all*!  (You set the method parameters to the fields' (default) values, rather than the other way around.)

Comment: Pass the date as primitive value to a constructor that takes the primitive and treats it like epoch seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use an `Object` of type [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse("16/01/2015");

Grocery milk = new Grocery("Milk", 2.84, date, "Food")
```

Alternatives include using a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object (which has more flexible/powerful date manipulation methods), or just storing your date as a `String`.

As for deciding whether you should use `setX()` methods or using a comprehensive constructor, unless there is a reason not to you can just have both available, and just use the most suitable at any one time.

Further reading:

- [Official Java Date & Time tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateintro.html)
- [Official Java Calendar tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/)

Comment: This answer is correct. But be aware that the java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java are notoriously troublesome. Many people instead use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new java.time package built into Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time). See [the Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).